# Visitor Design Pattern with Binary Expression Trees

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, visitor-pattern

I'm currently attempting to refactor some code to implement the visitor design pattern and I'm having trouble understanding conceptually what is going on.

The current code creates a binary expression tree based off a character array (that is an expression) and then traverses the tree in prefix order (using a traverse method within a Tree class, where the tree is also constructed) and then evaluates the expression within a "Calculator" class, which implements an "IVisitor" interface. The only method provided for this class is a visit method that returns an Object and needs a Node as its parameter. My Node class has an accept method (with an IVisitor object as the parameter) that is supposed to interact with the visit method.

I am not really sure how these pieces are supposed to come together and I've watched countless YouTube videos trying to figure out how to apply the visitor design pattern to this.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated, and if you need to see any code feel free to ask.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was forgetting was the differing types of operators (character) and operands (double). Once I realized this, within the visit() method, we can check if the node is an operator (internal node), further check which operator (+, -, /, *), then call accept() method on both left and right nodes (casting both to doubles) with the actual operator in-between.

Example:

```
if (n.getContent() == (Object) '+')
        d = (Double) n.getLeft().accept(this) + (Double) n.getRight().accept(this);
```

d being a Double variable. This will continue being called until we reach an operand (leaf node), which we check for within the visit() method by:

```
// If node has no children, we are at an operand (Double)
if (n.getLeft() == null && n.getRight() == null)
        return Double.parseDouble(n.getContent().toString());
```

This will return the value to original accept() call and will add the two values together in this instance.

Responding to save for later.